# Custom property in Directory.Build.props doesn't work in HintPath of a reference

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a Directory.Build.props located in the solution directory of my project in which I defined the following PropertyGroup with a custom property PureConfiguration:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.StartsWith('Debug'))">
        <PureConfiguration>Debug</PureConfiguration>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In my project I have the following reference defined:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="MyAwesomeReference">
        <HintPath>..\..\Runtime\$(PureConfiguration)\MyAwesomeReference\MyAwesomeReference.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Now when compiling it can't find the MyAwesomeReference.dll assembly (the file exists at this location, that is not the issue).

Through a

```
<Target>
     <Message Text="$(PureConfiguration)" />
</Target>
```

I can see that in the build console Debug is being outputed so the property is set.

Why does the HintPath then not work? When replacing $(PureConfiguartion) with Debug the error goes away and the project builds. So somehow when loading the reference this property is not set until then? Is there some kind of order that I have to consider?

Comment: The contents of the Directory.Build.props file should be imported ahead of the content in your project file and the properties in your .props file should be defined and available. Are you getting a compiler error message that '..\..\Runtime\\MyAwesomeReference\MyAwesomeReference.dll' can't be found? You could add a `Message` task to display `%(Reference.HintPath)` to confirm what value the HintPath is being set to. You could also use the MSBuild `-pp` argument (Preprocess), which will produce the output of all imports in order, to verify your property is defined before the reference.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I'm getting a compiler error that the MyAwesomeReference could not be resolved. Could not locate the assembly. By adding a Message to display %(Reference.HintPath) I get the following output: ..\..\Runtime\\MyAwesomeReference\MyAwesomeReference.dll.
My property does not to be set at this point it looks like. Why is that? As you said the first thing Microsoft.Common.props calls is the Directory.build.props file but is there a special case for references?

Comment: @JonathanDodds When I apply the MSBuild -pp argument I can't find the content of the Directory.build.props file in the output. Why is that? The content of the .csproj file appears on line 1705 to 1765

Comment: "... is there a special case for references?" No, there is no special case for references.

Comment: Where is the 'Directory.build.props' file in relation to the .csproj file? To be automatically found by MSBuild, it must be in the same directory or in a parent directory. i.e. 'Directory.build.props' must be in '.' or '..' or '..\..' or '..\..\..' etc. The first 'Directory.build.props' file found will be imported. (To support multiple files you can add `<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../'))" />` to each 'Directory.build.props' file. This same `import` works for 'Directory.build.targets' files.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonathanDodds I realized that my Directory.build.props file was actually placed in the wrong folder. Silly mistake on my side! I moved it to the correct location and the references started working. Thanks a lot for your help! The `<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('$(MSBuildThisFile)', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)../')) />` was very helpful at the end!